# iOS Image View - Height equal to the size of width

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm just to create an image that spans the entire screens width. The image is a square (512x512) and the idea is to scale to the width of the device while maintaining aspect ratio. I've tried doing this with contraints, setting the margins to `left: 0, top: 0, right: 0` and keeping the image at `aspect-fill`. The issue however, is that the image is becoming larger than the screens width, and thus the image is not only being cut off on the left and right, but is much taller than it should be.

How can I properly size an image to have the same width/height has the width of the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add constraints as shown in screenShot

Here for Positioning image view, I have given horizontal and vertical center constraints, that you can change according to your requirements(i.e wherever you want to place your imageview.)

Main idea here is to give these two constraints image view -

```
1.ImageView.width = superview.width
2.ImageView's aspect ratio(width/height) = 1.
```

[image]

Comment: I'm really confused as to how you gave it `superview.width` considering it's not an option in the editor? Typing it in reverts the constant to 0. Using the canvas size doesn't scale across all devices. Is there a way to type out your constraints, opposed to using the small UI at the bottom right?

Comment: I got it using `top, leading, trailing` instead of the width property. Thanks@

Comment: To add constraint superView.width to your image view, go to document outline, hold control and drag from your imageView to your superView you will get option of equal widths, just select it and you are done.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you didn't set constraints on the image view.
Set the following constraints on image view:

1) Set width of image view equal to width of self.view

2) Set aspect ratio 1:1 // This makes sure your image's height is equal to width

You would need additional constraints to specify the x and y position of the image view.